# How to Debug System.NullReferenceException When Running Transformation?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t4

I am attempting to generate code using T4 Text Templating, but when running the script, I get the error below:

```
Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB0A58A4C85EA3D7032675015C6052C89.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)
```

As I am unfamiliar with T4, I'm not sure exactly where to look to resolve this issue.

Comment: I can't find an inner exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to debug your template to find where the `NullReferenceException` is occurring.  Tim Larson has quick overview [here](http://adventuresindotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/debugging-t4-templates.html) and Oleg Sych has a more details [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/), along with his other excellent blog entries on T4.

Here's the short-short version:

1. Add debug="true" to template directive: `<#@ template debug="true" #>`
2. Launch debugger `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`
3. Break `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`
4. Select *New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio* in *Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger* dialog and click *Yes*
5. Debug your T4 template

Here is a simple example to help catch the `NullReferenceException` when calling ToString on bar:

```
<#@ template debug="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    object bar = null;  
#>
foo<#= bar.ToString() #>
```

Be sure to check first link though since on some versions you'll need to update the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting` to `0x2` to get things to behave correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Updated 2023

In Visual Studio, right click on a .tt file and click Debug T4 Template.

[Debugging a T4 Text Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/debugging-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your T4 template.
MSDN gives some help on [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126600.aspx).

In debug mode you can have a look at the generated classes in order to find out what went wrong.
T4 saves the generated code, assemblies and PDBs TEMP folder (%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp). The .cs file contains source code of the GeneratedTextTransformation. The .cmdline file contains command line options used to compile .cs file into .NET assembly (the .dll file).